# webpack does not recognize command-line options

Tags: webpack, webpack-cli

I feel kinda stupid asking this but can't find answers elsewhere.
I am upgrading the webpack for our product from v1 (yes) to v4 and I'm new to all this. I installed both webpack and webpack-cli:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/webpack -v

webpack-cli 4.0.0

webpack 4.44.2
```

but it does not recognize the options listed in the documentation like `-p`, `--optimize-minimize` etc.

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/webpack -p
[webpack-cli] Unknown argument: -p
```

What's the catch?

Answer (score 2):

Webpack v4+ will minify your code by default in production mode.

https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/

To minimise CSS: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/#minimizing-for-production

Comment: So this section of Webpack 4 documentation is incorrect: 
> Note that the --optimize-minimize flag can be used to enable TerserPlugin as well.
https://v4.webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#minify-the-output